# How to catch TableView creation in JavaFX 8

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I have a JavaFX application with a TableView that I need to fill up with data once the application starts. I am starting the application in the following manner:

```
private LayoutController theController;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    try {
     FXMLLoader fxmlload = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
     BorderPane root = (BorderPane )fxmlload.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,640,480);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
     theController = (LayoutController )fxmlload.getController();

     primaryStage.setTitle("Title Application");
     primaryStage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN,theController.windowStarted);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In my controller, called SampleController, I have the TableView object so that it (initially) creates some columns once it is up:

```
@FXML Parent myRoot;
@FXML TableView datTable<DataClass>;

private Stage theStage;

public EventHandler<WindowEvent> windowStarted = event -> {
  theStage = (Stage )myRoot.getScene().getWindow();
  getData();
};

protected void getData()
{
    dataTable.setEditable(false);
          .
          // Call a SOAP service to get the data
          .
}
```

I had assumed that once the Stage's WINDOW_SHOWN event occurs, the controls are created and I can do things with them. That apparently isn't the case. Apparently, controls specified using FXML are actually created sometime *after* the main application window is created!

What happens is that when the windowStarted lambda is executed, the getData() method gets called, but apparently the dataTable was not created before the WINDOW_SHOWN event occurred. As a result, I get NullPointerException failures when I try to call any of dataTable's methods!

I need to catch when the dataTable actually gets created so that I can use its methods. Is there some way to do this?

Someone please advise...

Comment: `@FXML TableView datTable<DataClass>;`: "datTable". Then you use it as `dataTable`. Is this a typo? How does this even compile? If it is not the case, then most probably the `fx:id` attribute in your FXML file is not (correctly) set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code for data download in method `initialize` which is called on controller after its root element has been completely processed or in other words after all FXML field are assigned.

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    //Here!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. One question: how do you get the controller to engage the initialize() function? Just putting it in the controller does not cause the controller to call it, and there doesn't seem to be any events associated with the controller or the root element that I can associate with the initialize function (there are only keyboard, mouse, and other input events).

Comment: There was a Initializable interface which controller could implement to be called, but now FXMLLoader will call this method automatically. Link to doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html

Comment: Yes, it appears to be the case. Unfortunately, it looks like the initialize() method, like the WINDOW_SHOWN event, is called *before* the dataTable is created. As a result, dataTable is still NULL when I attempt to call its methods. Adding his initilize method doesn't change anything.

Comment: That's stange. Did you assign the id in the fxml? Or could you post it?

Comment: I turns out I hadn't assigned the ID. That was the problem.It works now. Thanks...